# Hoods for 1993 Camapaganolo Chorus levers

Tags: brakes, vintage

The hoods for my [1993 camapaganolo chorus levers](http://velobase.com/ViewComponent.aspx?ID=15a43395-e3c7-4b2e-881f-50f23fc7718e) need replacing.

Can anyone suggest some inexpensive hoods that would be compatible apart from a period Campagnolo part?

Comment: If the existing hoods have not totally disintegrated, there is a product known as [liquid tape](http://www.globalindustrial.com/p/electrical/Wire-Connectors/Electrical1-Tape/black-liquid-electrical-tape?infoParam.campaignId=T9F&gclid=Cj0KEQjw27etBRDA3-ux4p3c58EBEiQAkJzTANR1yWt4XzIAwE3sLD6IAVVZhBp1rF1XWBEiYkHkXQEaAn2b8P8HAQ) that works fairly well to repair rubber parts of this sort.  (You would of course want to keep the gunk out of the mechanism, and it needs at least 24 hours to fully set.)

Comment: @DanielRHicks Thanks, I'll give that a try if I can't source some new ones. A quick google suggests it's not (cheaply) available in the UK, but there's probably a local equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

The best bet for old Campy Hoods is EBay.

The hoods you are looking for are the EC-R500 Silicone Rubber hoods, I believe.

One set here: http://www.ebay.com/itm/Campagnolo-8-9-Speed-Record-Ergo-Shifter-Hoods-pre-1998-EC-RE500-Genuine-/321946601034